# How does document.open affect history?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser-history

I fail to understand what the argument `replace` does. From the documentation:

> Optional. If set, the history entry for the new document inherits the history entry from the document which opened this document

Doesn't it mean that without `replace` the newly opened document will be added to history with its state?
This is how I'm opening it :

```
var newDoc = document.open("text/html");
newDoc.write(file);
newDoc.close();
```

And basically what I want is for the history buttons to remember those. I've been working with history.js and wondered if this could save me some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're citing [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_open.asp), which is [not very reliable](http://w3fools.com/). The [MDN documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.open) doesn't even mention that argument, and the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-72161170) states that `document.open` doesn't take any parameters (not even the content-type you're passing as the first argument). So there's not much hope that passing a value for `replace` is going to work cross-browser.

That being said, what I understand from the cited excerpt is the exact opposite of what you said: if you pass `true`, the new page will inherit the history of the opener document; if you don't, it starts a new history thread. Makes sense?

Comment: it does make sense but it doesn't actually do that, it has no affect on the history at all. but THANK you for notifying me about w3fools, i had no idea!

Comment: Then I guess you're safer just using `pushState` / `replaceState`.

Comment: These other variations on document.open are now documented on MDN, although note that they are deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open